# Unexpected { expected (?

Tags: php

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting '(' in /home/a7237281/public_html/include/session.php  on line 313

this is the error i get, relating to this code

```
      //check the emails
  $field = "email";  //Use field name for email
  $field2 = "email2";
  if(!$subemail || strlen($subemail = trim($subemail)) == 0)
  {
     $form->setError($field, "* Email not entered");
  }
  else if
  {
     /* Check if valid email address */
     $regex = "^[_+a-z0-9-]+(\.[_+a-z0-9-]+)*"
             ."@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]{1,})*"
             ."\.([a-z]{2,}){1}$";
     if(!eregi($regex,$subemail))
     {
        $form->setError($field, "* Email invalid");
     }
     else if ($subemail !== $subemail2)
     {
        $form->setError($field2, "* Emails does not match");
     }
     $subemail = stripslashes($subemail);
  }
  /* Check if email is already in use */
  else($database->emailTaken($subemail))
  {
    $form->setError($field, "* Email address already in use");
  }
```

And its referring to the { after the first else if.

I have edited with the entire piece of code, what could i do now?

Comment: http://php.net/if <--- read this ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course it is. You forgot to give a condition. Are you sure you meant `else if` and not just `else`?

Comment: And? You still don't have a condition.

Comment: @Luke: so? ;-) use `else` instead of `else if` if it is unconditional statement

Comment: `else($database->emailTaken($subemail))` hehehe

Answer (score 2):

Either put a condition for the if

```
else if(something ?!)
```

or remove the if so it reads

```
else
```